# Kill idle spark-shells and Apache Zeppelins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a team of engineers and data analysts who extensively use Zeppelin and many times they forget to turn it off and release resources.

What's the best solution to automatically kill idle jobs without hurting long-running jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible using Zeppelin version >=0.8:

> Before 0.8.0, Zeppelin don't have lifecycle management on interpreter.
>   User have to shutdown interpreters explicitly via UI. Starting from
>   0.8.0, Zeppelin provides a new interface `LifecycleManager` to control the lifecycle of interpreters. For now, there're 2 implementations:
>   `NullLifecycleManager` and `TimeoutLifecycleManager` which is default.

See [Interpreter Lifecycle Management](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/overview.html#interpreter-lifecycle-management)

Answer (score 1):

There's no current solution for stopping interpreter automatically.

Comment: Add more details to your answer so that it will help others what you are trying to convey and if possible provide any documentation which supports your answer.